# Use default data order in DataTables, but allow users to re-sort

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I am using the [Datatables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/index) to work with some data:

My problem is that I would like to present the data in the order it is provided initially. So, disable DataTables auto sort on execution. However, I still want to provide the users the option to sort the tables themselves. bSort:false allows me to disable the initial sorting, but it also disabled the user's ability to sort.

How can I achieve both? FYI, the data is provided in a randomized order.

Comment: I don't think datatables autosorts unless you tell it to.  Usually with the `aaSorting` param -http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you are looking for is "aaSorting". Leave "bSort" as is.

```
.dataTable({
    "bSort": true,
    "aaSorting": [],
    ...  //other datatables properties
 });
```

You can also set individual column sorting by applying "bSortable": True, or "bSortable": False to each column in "aoColumns".

```
.dataTable({
..., //other datatables properties 
"aoColumns": [
    { "bSortable": True },
    { "bSortable": False }
]
});
```

Comment: @David Very nice. Glad to hear it man. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Just as a note, the extra comma at the end of the non-sortable column will break in IE.  Any trailing commas on objects or arrays seem to freak IE out.

Comment: @GameCharmer Good fix. I've edited the answer to reflect this. I appreciate it.